# CMake and QT multiple definition

Tags: c++, qt, header, cmake, multiple-definition-error

I'm using a Qt and Cmake for a project and I'm a newbie with those two things, so please bear with me.

I have two class using Qt, one named `MapMaker` and another named `ImageLabel`. `MapMaker` inherited from `QMainWindow` and `ImageLabel` from `QLabel`

Imagelabel possess a Class as attribute that I named Map that possess a method addObstacle. MapMaker posses an imageLabel and ImageLabel possess a Map.

Every method of Map is in the Map.hpp file while MapMaker and ImageLabel method are in a .cpp file.

When I'm compiling, I have this error :

```
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/includes/Qtfiles/MapMakerv3.cpp.o: In function `Map::drawObstacle(int, int, bool)':
/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: multiple definition of `Map::addObstacle(int, int, bool)'
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: first defined here
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/includes/Qtfiles/imageLabel.cpp.o: In function `Map::drawObstacle(int, int, bool)':
/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: multiple definition of `Map::addObstacle(int, int, bool)'
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: first defined here
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/mapmakerv3_automoc.cpp.o: In function `Map::drawObstacle(int, int, bool)':
/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: multiple definition of `Map::addObstacle(int, int, bool)'
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/malcolm/AASS/sketch_maker/includes/MapInterpretation/Map.hpp:431: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/build.make:187: recipe for target 'mapmakerv3' failed
make[2]: *** [mapmakerv3] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mapmakerv3.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've double check all of my `ifndef` `define` (header guards) at the beginning of every header files and they are not the same.

What's funny is that if I `inline` the method `addObstacle` then the error disappear.

Here is my Cmake :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(mapmakerv3)

set (MapMaker_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (MapMaker_VERSION_MINOR 0)

find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )
  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  
endif()

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" ${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}  includes includes/Qtfiles includes/MapInterpretation/ includes/TopologicalMap/ includes/MapComparator/ Test/Ddata/)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
add_executable(mapmakerv3 main.cpp includes/Qtfiles/MapMaker.cpp includes/Qtfiles/imageLabel.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mapmakerv3 ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

install(TARGETS mapmakerv3 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
add_subdirectory(includes)
```

I tried to compile a test file with no Qt-dependant files (no ImageLabel nor MapMaker) and only some custom class I made and the compiling goes fine. My guess is that the error is linked to the Qt part (some project configuration I have not done or I donät know about) but I have no idea how.

The only error I know that throws a `multiple definition` error is a mistake in the header guards. What else could be the reason for this here ?

I know it's a pretty messy question for now, just tell me what information I should provide to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) only protects for multiple inclusion of the same header file in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (a source file with all headers). It does not protect against multiple definitions in different translation units.

Either make the function definitions `inline` (if it makes sense to do so) or move them into their own source file.

Comment: Inlining everything would be easier wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Malc Remember that `inline` is just a *hint* to the compiler, one the compiler can ignore (in which case the function is not inlined but still local in each translation unit and not exported). Also, making a function only makes sense for functions that *can* be inlined, like for example small functions in loops, simple getter or setter functions, etc. Larger or more complicated functions should really be put in a separate source file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the clear explanations. It is really helpful !